# "Review" a course?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I want to find a word to express relearning something. For instance, after taking a lecture you may find that something is still confusing and you go to learn it the second time by reading the textbook or possibly watching the record of the lecture.

I've searched the Internet for the phrase "course review" or "review a course", but what appeared to me were all about evaluating a course.

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101058/103153) I saw a phrase: brush up, I thought it would be a match for my case.

Comment: Review could maybe mean *to go through it slightly, not deeply*. Did you try "Reread" the book or "Rewatch" the lecture ?

Answer (score 1):

It’s fine.

When you review (AmE) or revise (BrE) something, you *study it again*, you *go over it again*, usually in preparation for an exam.

> We're **reviewing** (algebra) for the test tomorrow.
>
> We're **revising** (algebra) for the test tomorrow.
>
> Let’s **go over the rules** once more before we begin.
>
> I had to go back and **reread a few paragraphs** to see if I'd missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Review** is the perfect word to describe that.

You may also wish to "study" the course, though this word implies you aren't "relearning" anything, unless you're coming back to this subject after a long time.

"Course review" literally makes sense, but as you found people are using that as a synonym for a "course evaluation." Therefore, the context in which something like "course review" is seen will determine if it means reviewing material or a class itself.

Answer (score 0):

**To refresh** is a good candidate.

In [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refresh-sb-s-memory):

> **refresh** sb's memory = to help someone remember something:
>
> - I looked the word up in the dictionary to **refresh** my memory of its exact meaning.

In your context:

> I went through the course again to **refresh** my memory with the details.